# How to check data type in mysql?

Tags: mysql

**In PL/pgsql**,`pg_type()` give use data type of a variable.
As Example:

```
select pg_typeof(3) as type_of;
-- output: integer
select pg_typeof(true) as type_of;
-- output: boolean
```

**Similarly, how to check datatype of a variable in MySQL ?**

Comment: Provide an example where you "need" such.  Maybe we can help you find a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in function to return the type of a variable or expression in MySQL. You can review the list of built-in functions here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/built-in-function-reference.html

The closest thing I can think of is to run the `mysql` command-line client with the `--column-type-info` option.

```
% mysql --column-type-info

mysql> select 3, true;
Field   1:  `3`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       LONGLONG
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     2
Max_length: 1
Decimals:   0
Flags:      NOT_NULL BINARY NUM 

Field   2:  `true`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       LONGLONG
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     1
Max_length: 1
Decimals:   0
Flags:      NOT_NULL BINARY NUM 


+---+------+
| 3 | true |
+---+------+
| 3 |    1 |
+---+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But this output is only in the MySQL client. You can't use the result in SQL
expressions as if it were a built-in function.

Comment: Yes, right. We can see tables column type through commands
`desc <table_name> <column_nam>;`
or
`show columns from <table_name> like '<column_nam>';`

Comment: @ArtBindu Thanks for your comment! Please feel free to post an answer of your own.